# WordPress backend menu items not loading

Tags: wordpress, plugins, menu

On our website, we use the Ubermenu plugin. As I was creating a menu within WordPress' backend, the menu items suddenly no longer appeared. I've disabled Ubermenu and a bunch of other plugins but they just won't show. Has anyone come across this before?

Edit to add: Also, I just noticed that the Screen Options and Help tabs on the top of the page also don't work. But work fine on every other page.

[image: Missing Menu Items]

[image: Screen Options and Help tab links don't open the dropdown menu]

Answer (score 0):

There are some js errors in console?

Or, do you edit some files inside wp-includes folder?

Comment: No, no changes have been made to the core files. It was working fine and then immediately upon page reload they suddenly weren't there anymore.

Comment: Try to reinstall WP 4.6.1